# Enable and Disable array of textBoxes by check boxes

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox, textbox

i have been working on this code ! 
and i couldn't done it right .

what i want is the text box to be enabled when the corresponding checkbox is checked .
but when apply the function nothing happens :(

in my code  the text and check boxes are dynamically generated from database using php .
here is my code :

```
<div><div class="ac-container">

<div id="accordion">

<?php

$qry="SELECT * FROM catalog";
$result= mysql_query($qry);
if($result){
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

print "<h3><a href=\"\#\"> cat:".$info['name']."</a></h3><div>";

$qryitem="SELECT * FROM item WHERE Id=". $info['Cid'];
$resultitem=mysql_query($qryitem);
if($resultitem){

?>

<form name="form1" id="form" method="post" action="manage_item_action.php"  >
<?php
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($resultitem))
{
?>
<input type="checkbox"  id="checkB" name="op[]" value="<?php echo $info['Id'];?>" />   <?php echo $info['name'];?>
<label> Quantity <input disabled="disabled" id="textB" type="text" 
name="Quantit[]" value="<?php echo $info['Quantity'];?>"/>
</label>
<script>



 checkBoxes=document.form1.elements['op[]'];
 textBoxes=document.form1.elements['Quantit[]'];
 for(var i=0 ; i<checkBoxes.length;i++){
 checkBoxes[i].onchange = function() {
 textBoxes[i].disabled =!(this.checked);};


 }

 </script>



<br/>

        <?php
        } 
    }


 else echo "There are no items.";

 print "</div>";



}
}


?>

</div>

<input type="submit" value="update" name="submit"/>
<input type=reset value="clear"></td></tr> </form>
```

Comment: That's some sloppy code you got there. Your loop makes you end up with a bunch of duplicated JavaScript all with closing tags.

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you mean by "a bunch of duplicated JavaScript all with closing tags."

Comment: can you post the rendered html it creates?

Comment: ok i edited the post ! i added more details . the php creats only the text and check boxes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that inside your event handler the variable `i` is not defined. To overcome this problem, you could add a property to each checkbox to save what index they are referring to:

```
checkBoxes=document.form1.elements['op[]'];
textBoxes=document.form1.elements['Quantit[]'];
for(var i=0 ; i<checkBoxes.length;i++)
{
    checkBoxes[i].myIndex = i;
    checkBoxes[i].onchange = function() {
        textBoxes[this.myIndex].disabled =!(this.checked);
    };
}
```

Other methods to solve this problem: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/referencedvariables.html

Your code is still pretty messed up. For instance you are generating too many closing `<div/>`-tags with your first `print`-statement. I would suggest you just remove the PHP-code from your question, as the question is only related to html and javascript.

I would also suggest to use a library for manipulating DOM elements like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

When writing and debugging javascript, you should always make sure that you get error messages. "nothing happens" is a sign that you are just ignoring errors. For Firefox download the addon `Firebug`. Safari also has developer tools that you can activate in the settings. Using these tools will make it very easy to spot and solve problems like this.

Comment: Thank you very much ! it worked with me ! and thank you for your comment about the jQuery for DOM elements